# Rails one-to-many through a joint table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, one-to-many

I have following models in my recent project:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # setup association
  has_one :user_detail
  has_one :employee
  has_one :company, :through => :employee
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
  has_many :users, :through => :employees
end
```

To build a nested form for user sign up, I need to build company in the User#new action, however, I tried following code but not working.

```
def new
  @user = User.new()
  @company = @user.build_company()
end
```

The error shows there is no build_company method for @user.

So I tried another approach:

```
def new
  @user = User.new()
  @company = @user.company.build()
end
```

Still not working. The error shows `build()` is not a method for nil class.

Does rails not support this kind of one-to-many through joint table approach?

Comment: did you already set accepts_nested_attributes_for :employee in your user model?

Comment: @Mattherick: I think "accepts_nested_attributes_for :employee" is only needed when I submit form, but before I submit form I need a empty instance of company in the memory to render the form.

Comment: if you set accepts_nested_attributes_for :employee in your user model, then the normal build methods, like you tried in you new action, should be available.

Comment: @Mattherick: not working. `u = User.new.build_company` will return "NoMethodError: undefined method `build_company' for #<User:0x2def640>"

Comment: Did you tried accepts_nested_attributes_for :company already?

Answer (score 0):

Go for

```
@company = Company.new(user: @user)
```

or

```
@company = @user.build_employee.build_company
```